# Getting the real request string in Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm having some trouble implementing a sort of oddball spec using Jersey, and it would help me if I could get the raw request string.

Basically the spec calls for requests that end in ? and ?? to be processed separately, but from what I can tell, UriInfo doesn't give you a request string back, but a URI object, which chops the last ? off. So I can't distinguish requests that ended in one ? from those that ended in none.

Any idea how I would go about getting the raw request string? Or should I just give up and use a raw Servlet?

Comment: Oh great, the Servlet API doesn't pass that info on, either.